# Creating autohide custom view in android

Tags: android, animation, view

I am working on creating a custom view in android. I want to create an autohide custom view control.
This control will be holding other UI elements  mostly buttons or icons. It has a small button which is mandatory, clicking which will slide the control in or out thus changing its visibility.
one should be able to add other buttons or icons to this control
The control can be placed only at the borders, which needs to be specified while creating the view.
I don't know how to start with it 
Should I be extending the View class or ViewGroup class.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [this](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/sliding-drawer-again.html)

and then you have to add a dynamic layout to this drawer

Answer (score 1):

I used a `RelativeLayout` and added a `Button` to the `View`.

When I call `expandView()` or `collapseView()`, I call `mybutton.setVisibility()` and let `RelativeLayout` know it has changed with `this.requestLayout()`.